# Create list item SharePoint online Rest API 403 - Forbidden

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a new list item in a SharePoint list on SPO.

I am getting forbidden 403 error.

```
var listURL = webURL + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Departments')/items"; 
                 $.ajax({  
             url: listURL,
             type: "POST",  
             headers: {  
                 "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                 "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
             },  
             data: JSON.stringify({  
                                 '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.' + pListName + 'ListItem' },
                                 'Title': 'Test1'}),
                                 
            
             success: function(data) {  
                 console.log(data.d.results);  
                 alert("Item added")
             },  
             error: function(error) {  
                 alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
             }  
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not allow anonymous requests (your request appears to be anonymous). You need to be authenticated (logged in).

Comment: I get the value for _spPageContextInfo and I am getting a forbidden for post. I do not get 403 error for get method.